# How add element to div in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i want to add element to div in angularjs. so write this code but not work correctly. thanks for your help :)

```js
function TestController($scope) {
$scope.addElement = function(){
    var myElements = angular.element(document.querySelector('#form'));
    console.log(myElements);
    if(myElements.length == 0)
     alert("Not Find");
    else
        myElements.prepend( myElements[0].children[1]);
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController" id="form">
    <input type="button" ng-click="addElement()" value="add"></input>
    <div id="div">
      <input type="text" name="name">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, could you be more clear with your question? What element do you want to add to where?

Comment: it add element to div. when click on button it add input element on first child and add button put in second child.

Comment: @timeiscoffee i want to add input element to div.

Comment: Don't change the DOM in your controller, use a directive for that

Comment: Don't you need to add more buttons on the dom ?

Comment: @ Vineet yes. i want to add input element. i update my html code in question. in fact i want to add <div id="div"> other element</div> to div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have tried.

```
$scope.addElement = function(){
    var myElements = angular.element(document.querySelector('#form'));
    console.log(myElements)

   console.log(myElements[0].children[1])
    if(myElements.length == 0)
     alert("Not Find");
    else{
        html = angular.element(myElements[0].children[1]).clone();  
        myElements.append( html);
    }
```

You should use angular clone method.

EDIT.

Here it the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2kV5Vsm6i03ZNNh5Bi7?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to append an input element to div on each ng-click?

You just need to target the div with jquery and append the element with it.

See example: http://jsbin.com/seyawemijo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thanks for your reply. i want to add element by id. because may be my form be complex.

Comment: @HJZ I updated the example to set id to the appended text input.

Answer (score 1):

Often than not when you want to modify the DOM directly, there is a way to do it without.

"Thinking in Angular way"

```js
function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.textArr = [];
  var count = 1;

  $scope.addElement = function() {
    var ele = {
      model: 'hello ' + count++
    }

    $scope.textArr.push(ele);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController" id="form">
  <input type="button" ng-click="addElement()" value="add" />

  <div ng-repeat="text in textArr">
    <input type="text" ng-model="text.model">
  </div>

  <div>{{textArr}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   myElements.prepend(myElements[0].children[1].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have altered the above solution to add other attributes(including id) to the input text element

```
var globalCntr = 0;
function TestController($scope) {
   $scope.addElement = function() {
        globalCntr ++;
        $('<input>',{
          type:'text',
          id:('inputText'+globalCntr)
       }).appendTo($('#target'));
   };
}
```